# Load additional data for named range

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Given I have the following on "Sheet 1"

[image]

Currently each value is a named range (Pokemon, Type, Weakness and Basic?)

This is the named range for Pokemon:

[image]

What I would like to do, is rather than having a named range for each, I just want one for Pokemon and to have Type, Basic, Weakness etc pulled in from the other columns in the named range sheet, so that the named range sheet would look like:

[image]

And then I don't need a range for Type, Basic etc as it would be pulled in from the named range sheet.

Not sure what to Google to find the answer to this nor am I sure if this is possible.

Comment: Try index() with match() and there are a couple of questions on here with examples.

Answer (score 0):

Huge thanks to @Solar Mike for their hinting comment. I was able to use the following formula to grab the needed data:

```
=INDEX(Pokemon!A2:C100, MATCH(A2, Pokemon!A2:A100), 2)
```

Where `Pokemon!A2:A100` is the list of Pokemon, `A2:C100` is the list of Pokemon and their data (type, weakness etc) and `A2` from the current sheet is the Pokemon I wish to look up.